# Asymmetric encryption in Blazor client

Tags: c#, cryptography, blazor, .net-6.0, encryption-asymmetric

Using .net 6.0, Blazor web app (no server side).

I'm trying to implement asymmetric encryption in the client, for many reasons.  I'd like to generate client-side pub/pri keys and encrypt/decrypt functions (started looking for RSA, but open to anything safe).  The standard .NET Cryptography classes aren't supported in the browser, and I've also tried Nuget's jose-jwt (seems still dependent on .NET Cryptography libs), and Nuget's Chilkat (not ready for 6.0, anybody know where the source is?), and looked at Nuget's PkcsExtensions.Blazor but it's convoluted so not sure if there's an answer in there.

Any suggestions at all to accomplish the stated goal (other than 'don't do that') would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTTP (TKS) since Net 4.7.2 is no done in operating system instead of Net.  The encryption modes didn't always work with Net.  See : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Comment: I didn't down vote.   People often down vote and I just ignore the negative comments.  May be it is because you are using older encryption modes that are prone to attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use JS-Interop to tap into the native encryption libraries in WASM.